# App for monitoring 3G network availability

Tags: android, networking, mobile

Is there an app to monitor and log 3G network availability, that could inform me when my phone has (and had) no network? A couple of times now I noticed that the  phone calls did not get through, or I would glance at my phone and see no signal. This would happen at locations where I usually have signal.

I would like to know exactly how often this happens. Because I have my phone so that I can be reached in case of a family emergency, and if my signal disappears too often I'm going to switch carriers.

Comment: While waiting for answers, you can take a look at my corresponding app listings: [Bad Signal Alert](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_cellsignal#group_404) for the first part, and [Monitoring & Mapping](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_cellsignal#group_403) for the second.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Do you want me to turn that in to an answer or will you ?

Comment: Once you've found a combination that really fits your case, yes please :) Feel free to link to the list for "further possible candidates" then – but make your answer specific to the app (or combination) you've chosen (with their links), and  include how that meets your requirements plus how well they work (ie. not just a one-liner, but some details). Glad my pointer helped you, and looking forward to your answer!